# Defining a string as char* vs unsigned char*

Tags: c

I am using the [pcre2](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html) library, and it has a special 'string-type' defined as `PCRE2_SPTR8`.

If I try and initialize a string with something like:

```
PCRE2_SPTR8 s =   "my string";
```

I'll get a warning such as:

```
warning: initializing 'PCRE2_SPTR8' (aka 'const unsigned char *') 
         with an expression of type 'char [27]' converts between pointers to
         integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
```

What would be the suggested way to initialize this type of string? Doing something like:

```
PCRE2_SPTR8 s =   (PCRE2_SPTR8) "my string";
```

Additionally, out of curiosity why is a normal "string" usually defined as `char* string = "something";` instead of `unsigned char* string = "something";`. Is there any advantage/disadvantage of defining a string with a signed vs. unsigned char?

Comment: `char` is weird in that compilers can treat it as either default signed, or default unsigned because *reasons*. As such, your character constants will inherit this and forcing unsigned might break things.

Comment: @tadman what are a few of the reasons you can think of?

Comment: Differences of opinion now fossilized into the C standard.

Comment: Because the C-Standard leaves whether `char` is signed or unsigned up to the implementation. See [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/3422102) (just another way they have found to torment C programmers `:)`

Comment: @carl.hiass In C, `int, long, short` without `signed` is _signed_. To extend that idea to `char` makes it also _signed_ - so seems natural.  Yet signed `char` is very problematic for non-2's complement as now there are two 0 encodings (or worse a trap).  Such machines benefitted with `char` as unsigned.  Also [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)  used a 0-255 character encoding unlike ASCII 0-127, and benefits with an unsigned `char`.  C compromise: `char` is a type different than `signed char` and `unsigned char` and matchings the range/size of one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the suggested way to initialize this type of string?

Something like OP's idea when `PCRE2_SPTR8` is not `char *`, but it is more common to avoid hiding the `*`.  As this is a style issue - follow your group's style guide.

```
// PCRE2_SPTR8 s =   (PCRE2_SPTR8) "my string";
const unsigned char * =  (unsigned char *) "my string";
```

---

> Additionally, out of curiosity why is a normal "string" usually defined as `char* string = "something";` instead of `unsigned char* string = "something";`.

In C, a *string* is defined by the standard library as:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

It is best to stay close to that definition. `char* string` is not a *string*, but a pointer to a *string*.  Like-wise for `unsigned char* string`.

---

> Is there any advantage/disadvantage of defining a string with a `signed` vs. `unsigned char`?

The C library of string functions behave *as if* the string elements were `unsigned char`.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

This is important in select case like in `strcmp()` and comparing two characters, maybe one outside the ASCII range.  The values are compared as if `unsigned char`.  Also important on rare platforms today that do not use 2's complement.

When implementing a string-like function, then best to implement with `unsigned char`.

When calling string functions, best to stay with `char` to minimize need for casting.

Comment: I think that about covers it `:)`